# External Tables: How Handle Schema Changes of underlying data

Tags: databricks-unity-catalog

I create `external tables` in `unity catalog`. Is table `drop` and re-`create` the only option to handle schema changes of the underlying data (such as `Delta`, `CSV`,..) such as described [here](https://community.databricks.com/t5/community-discussions/unity-catalog-external-table-lastupdateversion/td-p/53960)?